# EventListeners Fetching classes with label tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, targeting

I have an Event Listener that grabs an element by its class name, if the input tags name is the same as that class. It works for the first label but it doesn't work for the second label. Am I using event targeting incorrectly? See Below.

JS

```
let selected = true;
document.querySelector('label').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked = selected) {
    let labelFor = document.querySelector('label').htmlFor;
    let inputId = document.getElementById(labelFor);
    let inputName = inputId.name;
    let path = document.getElementsByClassName(inputName)
    console.log(path);
  }
})
```

HTML

```
Formatted HTML:
<input type="radio" name="first" id="floor-1">
<label for="floor-1">first</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="second" id="floor-2">
<label for="floor-2">second</label>
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
   <g class="first">
      <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
   </g>
   <g class="second">
      <path d="M 20 20 H 100 V 100 H 20 L 20 20" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Any guidance would be extremely helpful.

Comment: `if (e.target.checked = selected) {` - this is an assignment, not a comparison. You probably meant to write two or three equal signs and `document.querySelector('label')` will only select the first `label`

Comment: Thank you I missed that. However now the function doesn't work at all lol

Comment: If you want to add event listeners on multiple labels, consider using `document.querySelectorAll` or you could take advantage of event bubbling and add a single event listener on the common parent element of all the `label` elements.

Comment: I've tried document.querySelectorAll but I get this error document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener is not a function
I'll look for documentation on event bubbling then

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, you need to call `.forEach` on the return value of `document.querySelectorAll` and then add the event listener on each item in the list returned by `document.querySelectorAll`. Look up the details of this method on MDN, that will clear things up.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

```js
// since the handler is going to be associated
// with more than one html element, provide it
// as separate function which reduces overhead.
function handleControlStateChange(evt) {

  const elmControl = evt.currentTarget;
  const svgRoot = document.body.querySelector('svg');

  if (svgRoot && elmControl && elmControl.checked) {

    const pathContainer = svgRoot.getElementsByClassName(elmControl.name)[0];

    const elmPath = pathContainer && pathContainer.children[0];
    const pathValue = elmPath && elmPath.getAttribute('d');

    console.log(pathValue);
  }
}

// initialize event listeners, but for the
// "change" event of each checkbox control.
document.body.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]').forEach(elm =>
  elm.addEventListener("change", handleControlStateChange)
);
```

```html
<label>
  <!--
    provide a simpler stucture and thus, reduced html overhead as with
    `for` and `id` attributes, as well as with the code which handles
    the state changes of a checkbox-control.
  //-->
  <span class="label">first</span>
  <!--
    make use of a checkbox- instead of a radio-control since differently
    named radio-controls do not make sense because there will be no radio-
    group that contains both controls; thus each radio could not be unchecked.
  /-->
  <input type="checkbox" name="first"/>
</label>

<label>
  <span class="label">second</span>
  <input type="checkbox" name="second"/>
</label>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <g class="first"> 
    <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
  </g>
  <g class="second"> 
    <path d="M 20 20 H 100 V 100 H 20 L 20 20"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected because `document.querySelector('<CSS selector>')` returns the first element within the document that matches with the `<CSS selector>` specified.

So in your case,

- It encounters the ***#floor-1*** input field's label
- Then attaches the event listener to that field alone.

If you need to listen to ***all*** the labels in your HTML file, use

```
document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(eachLabelElem => 
   eachLabelElem.addEventListener("click",<your function logic here>)
)
```

Note that the Event Listener will be applied to all the `label` present in your HTML.

Comment: Thank you I was just trying this and unfortunately nothing is happening. Heres the code
document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(item => {
                item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    if (event.target.checked) {
                        let labelFor = document.querySelector('label').htmlFor;
                        console.log(labelFor);
                    }
                })
            })

Comment: I presume that you are trying to perform some logic when you either click on `label` or the `radio` input. If so, you need to add the eventListener to `input` instead of `label`. Moreover `label` does not have a checked attribute; radio input does